# Get the used selector in an element selected with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get the selector that was used to find an element with jquery? For example
I select an element like this:

```
<span class="test1">lala</span>

a = $('.test1, .test2')
```

Is there a property in `a` that holds the `.test1` selector string?
The only solution I can think about is to ittearte over all selectors and test if they match

```
var selectors = ['.test1', '.test2'];

a = $(selectors.join(','))

var selector = selectors.find(function(s)return a.is(s))
```

Comment: How about using like this?
a.class();

Answer (score 2):

You could use .selector but it's deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9

```
console.log(a.selector) //returns .test
```

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: So I can't use it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As [Anton mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378309/157247), the [built-in way](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) to do this was deprecated (for various very good reasons) a while back and has been removed.

The reliable way to do this is:

```
var sel = ".test";
a = $(sel);
a.data("selector", sel);
```

If you need to do this a lot, use a function to encapsulate it

```
function $memo(selector) {
    return $(selector).data("selector", selector);
}
// Usage:
a = $memo(".test");
```

Then any time you need to know, you can get the selector from `data`:

```
var sel = a.data("selector");
```

Comment: This will only work if I have one selector. I updated my question to make my indention more clear.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle: Well that rather changes things, or arguably, doesn't. `a`'s selector **is** `".test1, .test2"`. `a` may have elements matching one class, the other, or both. If you want to know whether a specific element within `a` matches one or the other, you have to ask (via `hasClass` or `is`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy. Because the way Anton did it is deprecated.
But the event variable contains the selector very hidden.

Have a look at how I achieved it:

```
$('.test, .test2').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log 'Selector: ', e.currentTarget.classList[0]
}
```

**Here is also a working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fKyZ4/2/

Comment: This will only work if the selector is a single class name. I'm looking for a more generic version, where I get the selector jQuery is using to get the element.

Comment: If you don't want the string of the class, but the HTML element that jQuery is using: Just use `e.currentTarget` :)

Comment: @DominikSchmidt: Or, you know, `this`.

Comment: Oh, totally forgot `this`